# Having one single generic Viewset that can be resolved through its router basename on Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My question is more about refactoring, best practices and potential vulnerability while organizing my routes and views in DRF.

My app is really a simple one and all the views are to be described in the same fashion. Take my views.py file for example:

```
# views.py
class TrackView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Track.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TrackSerializer

class AlbumView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Album.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TrackSerializer

class ArtistView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Artist.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArtistSerializer

class ChartView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Chart.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChartSerializer
```

And in urls.py I can do:

```
#urls.py

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'tracks', TrackView)
router.register(r'albums', AlbumView)
router.register(r'artists', ArtistsView)
router.register(r'charts', ChartsView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

In this scenario every new View is a copied logic of each other only changing the name of the model they use, and for every new model added that needs a view I would basically have to create the same repeated code in urls.py and views.py.

Instead of doing like that I refactored it like this:

```
# views.py
from rest_framework import viewsets


class APIView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        return eval(self.basename).objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return eval(self.basename+'Serializer')


# urls.py

from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from top_charts.views import *
from .routes import ROUTE_NAMES

router = DefaultRouter()

for route in ROUTE_NAMES:
    router.register(r''+route.lower()+'s', APIView, basename=route)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]

# Here in routes.py would be the only place I'd need to update when I have a new model

ROUTE_NAMES = [
    'Track',
    'Album',
    'Artist',
    'Chart'
]
```

It works, and I can access the urls of all endpoints just fine and it has a much cleaner code. My question is: is this a good practice or do you see any problem with my implementation?

There are always concerns when it comes to the use of eval()  but I could not think pragmatically what could go wrong in here since ROUTE_NAMES is the one that would define the evaluation and that would totally be under my control, so it doesn't seem like a place where I leave for potential vulnerability.

Also I don't see this sort of implementation suggestion anywhere in DRF documentation. They always go for the repeated code logic of views, which left me suspicious and wondering why.

Answer (score 0):

Part by part:

About the URLs, I don't think what you have done is very wrong, but it is certainly not a good practise. I see three main issues.

1. Having the routes in the URLs file makes you able to see the views and paths directly. Separating those into two files is not really useful. You save 2 lines of code, but that doesn't make the code more efficient and it doesn't make it cleaner either.
2. A problem that you might have is that whenever you need to add a route that doesn't follow the same pattern as all other ones you have, you'll have to add it separately. Or if you have to modify one of the already existing ones you'll have to remove the item from the list and, again, add another route separately. You've got more files and data to maintain but every route could be clearly defined in one line in `urls.py`.
3. Suppose you have the following:

```py
ROUTE_NAMES = [
    'Track',
    'Album',
    'Artist'
    'Chart'
]
```

It looks the same, right? But a comma is missing after the third element, and now you've got an app that works in a completely different without crashing while running the server, because the code is actually completely fine. Having the routes that way is a source of errors that would be easily avoided just by having one `router.register` per line.

About the views, I also have 2 main concerns.

1. The first one is basically the points 1 and 2 I've explained about the URLs combined: you save lines of code but that doesn't make the code that more efficient, and the moment you need to add more functionalities to one view you'll have to remake it because there's no way for you to modify only one leaving the others the way they are.
2. A big concern is on the use of `eval`, as you had already guessed. Yes, I too fail to see a way to exploit that, but isn't it better to just not use it? If you *really need* to save those few lines of code, there are other ways to do what you intend without using `eval` or other dangerous methods. For example, using `getattr`:

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets
from . import models, serializers


class APIView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        return getattr(models, self.basename).objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return getattr(serializers, self.basename + 'Serializer')
```

This way, the exact same is achieved without using a too dangerous method, limiting the items you can get to whatever has been declared or imported in `models.py` and `serializers.py`, instead of allowing the execution of any expression. However, this is still not recommended because the problem I've stated in point 1 remains.

At the start of your question you talk about refactoring. I would say that Django and DRF don't really consider refactoring in their guides and docs because they provide very simple examples and use cases for their software. Your example application is very small too, and the code is very clean, so there's no real reason to refactor that. I could talk for hours about when and how to refactor code, but as a general rule don't refactor anything that is clearly understandable if efficiency is not critical.